# How to save bitmap (or png) of MS Access Form Web Browser Control (QR code)

Tags: vba, ms-access, qr-code

I have a form where I create a QR code within a web browser control from a local html file with JavaScript.

I want to save that QR code as a bitmap or png into a folder.

The error

> ActiveX component can't create object

is on the line

```
Set bmp = CreateObject("System.Drawing.Bitmap")
```

```vb
Private Sub cmd_GenQRCode_Click()
    
    'Generate the QR code
    Dim sCmd As String
    sCmd = "qrcode.makeCode('" & Me.txt_QRCodeContent & "');"
    oWebBrowserObject.Document.parentWindow.execScript (sCmd)

    'Create and save a .png
    Dim bmp As Object
    Dim wbObj As Object
    Dim wbDoc As Object
    Dim wbBody As Object

    Set wbObj = Me.WebBrowser0.Object
    Set wbDoc = wbObj.Document

    'Create a new bitmap with the dimensions of the Web Browser control
    Set bmp = CreateObject("System.Drawing.Bitmap")

    'Draw the contents of the Web Browser control onto the bitmap
    Set wbBody = wbDoc.body
    Call bmp.SetPixel(0, 0, RGB(255, 255, 255))
    Call wbBody.DrawToBitmap(bmp, Rectangle(Me.WebBrowser0.left, Me.WebBrowser0.top, Me.WebBrowser0.width, Me.WebBrowser0.height))

    'Save the bitmap as a PNG file
    bmp.SaveAsPNG "C:\Documents\example.png"

    Set wbObj = Nothing
    Set wbDoc = Nothing
    Set wbBody = Nothing
    Set bmp = Nothing

End Sub
```

The rectangle function:

```vb
Public Function Rectangle(ByVal left As Long, ByVal top As Long, ByVal width As Long, ByVal height As Long) As Object

    Dim rect As Object
    Set rect = CreateObject("System.Drawing.Rectangle")
    rect.left = left
    rect.top = top
    rect.width = width
    rect.height = height
    Set Rectangle = rect
    
End Function
```

The QR code generates and populates the web browser control.

Current references included are `system.drawing.dll` and `microsoft internet controls` amongst the other standards.

Using MS Access 2019

Comment: What library are you using for qrcode()?

Comment: Review https://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/threads/qrcode-image-generator.299675/

Comment: And https://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/threads/qr-code-generator-image-using-zxing-zebra-crossing-library.319054/

Comment: @TomRobinson I am using qrcode.min.js

Comment: @June7 i reviewed those 2 links and appreciate the pointer. However, the first requires an outside excel file and i'm trying to keep it all local within just the access module. The second requires a regedit to add a library which I would prefer to avoid for implementation. I didn't think just bitmapping a webpage would be difficult, but looks like it is!

Comment: @TomRobinson more specifically...jQuery v1.8.3 jquery.com

Comment: An issue seems to be the IE7 browser access uses natively. I can regedit to get rid of the problem, but again I am trying to avoid regedits on end user systems. So really this is how to make a bmp/png from an IE7 page.